# Integral of a Polynomial in Python

Tags: python, polynomials, polynomial-math, calculus

How would we write a function in python that returns the definite integral of a polynomial between two points (`X_1` and `X_2`)?

The function takes 3 arguments:

- a list `A` of polynomial coefficients (i.e. for polynomial `f(x)=5x^4−2x+1`, this list becomes `A=[5,0,0,−2,1]`)
- a real number `X_1`
- a real number `X_2`

We are given the formula for the definite integral of a polynomial such as
[image: We are given the formula for the definite integral of a polynomial such as]

My attempt at this function is below, however the output returns `0.2`

```py
    def take_integral(A, X_1, X_2):

            integral = 0

            for i in range(len(A)):
                integral = A*(X_2**(i+1) - X_1**(i+1))/(i+1)
            return integral

    print(take_integral([1, 2, 1], 0, 3))
```

The expected result from the function should be:

```py
    print(take_integral([1, 2, 1], 0, 3))
    21.0
    print(take_integral([5, 0, 0, -2, 1], 0, 1))
    1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points here:

- There's a serious problem with multiplying `A` with the whole bunch of stuff afterwards. `A` is a list, where the rest gives a float. The computer doesn't necessarily know what to do with that. Imagine if I told you to multiply a set of crayons by 4. You can guess what I want, but ultimately, it doesn't really make sense. You want to multiply the **contents** of the list instead of the list **itself**.
- With your given formula for computing a definite integral of a polynomial, I'm pretty sure there should be a sum where you add all the terms together. That's what the definition of a polynomial is, right? Currently, you're computing each term and erasing the previous term. So, you need to add them up instead.
- Your attempt also kind of..."flips" the exponents. Since the list of coefficients `A` is sorted in descending order of power (`A[0]` being the coefficient of the highest power), doing `X_1**(i+1)` when `i=0` in your sample input where `A=[1,2,1]` would be multiplying the highest power with the lowest exponent instead of the desired `3`. So you want to iterate through the list from left to right, but your `i` when you're raising your `X`'s needs to decrease. Thankfully, `len(A)` comes in handy for solving that.

  - If you do `len(A)-i`, you'll get exactly the `i+1` according to the formula. This is true since `len(A)` will give the one more than the highest power in your polynomial, and `i` starts from `0` to one less than the length of `A`, and as a result gives you `i+1` as per the formula.

Here's the code that will give you the right answers:

```
def take_integral(A, X_1, X_2):

        integral = 0

        for i in range(len(A)):
            integral += A[i]*(X_2**((len(A))-i) - X_1**((len(A))-i))/((len(A))-i)
        return integral

print(take_integral([1, 2, 1], 0, 3))
21
print(take_integral([5, 0, 0, -2, 1], 0, 1))
1
```

Comment: wow thanks for the detailed response! that clears things up a lot.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

In your function you ignore X_1 and X_2 and set them both to 0. Hence the result is always 0

Comment: thanks for that. I took away the `X_1 = 0` and `X_2 = 0` and now the function outputs 0.2 for everything?

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done more efficiently using numpy libraries.

```
import numpy as np 

def take_integral(A, X_1, X_2):
    powers = np.flipud(np.array(range(len(A)))) + 1 # Create an array
    A = A/ powers # adjust coefficients
    return np.sum(A * (X_2 ** powers - X_1 ** powers))
```